# What's the best way to make Shorten URL

Tags: ruby-on-rails

My question is simple, what is the best solution to shorten `URL` using `ruby on Rails` ? thank you

Answer (score 2):

use the **gem bitly** its good and easy to implement http://rubygems.org/gems/bitly

Comment: is an external service really a good idea ?

Comment: i have used it in my application and found it useful and nice you can have a try..

Answer (score 1):

I have used https://github.com/zigotto/googl in the past. The real icing on the cake for it is the analytics support you get along with it.

Using it is really simple:

```
url = Googl.shorten('http://www.zigotto.com')

url.short_url
=> "http://goo.gl/ump4S"

url.long_url
=> "http://www.zigotto.com/"

url.qr_code
=> "http://goo.gl/ump4S.qr"

url.info
=> "http://goo.gl/ump4S.info"
```

To revert the operation, use:

```
url = Googl.expand('http://goo.gl/ump4S')

url.long_url
=> "http://www.zigotto.com/"
```

Comment: is an external service really a good idea ?

Comment: Your other options would be extremely more expensive. For starters, a .ly domain will cost you $75 in registry charges itself. You'll then need to host this site somewhere, ensure that it's always up and write **an external** service to map short URLs to real ones. While you may pursue this course of action, you should be asking what business you are in. _There is a reason why people and companies strive to do one thing really well in world markets._

Comment: what about create your own shortener in your app, or using a gem like this https://github.com/jpmcgrath/shortener, have you an idea ? i also found this tuto to create your shorten url http://jamespmcgrath.com/a-simple-link-shortener-in-rails/

Comment: Following the requirements in second link, if your needs are modest and you don't need to shorten your URLs to the smallest possible length, you can definitely roll out your own (Hey, Rails makes it easy!). However, if I were to do that, I'd calculate the cost of my time and compare it with that of using another service.